# How to make pandas groupby not lazy?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

It is mentioned in this tutorial that pandas groupby object is lazy.

> it’s lazy in nature. It doesn’t really do any operations to produce a
>   useful result until you say so.

and

> It’s also worth mentioning that .groupby() does do some, but not all,
>   of the splitting work by building a Grouping class instance for each
>   key that you pass. However, many of the methods of the BaseGrouper
>   class that holds these groupings are called lazily rather than at
>   **init**(), and many also use a cached property design.

So I made some tests to make sure that groupby is really lazy.

Let

```
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,size=(1000000,4)))
```

then

```
%timeit gg=df.groupby(1)
35.6 µs ± 110 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

which almost takes no time. And

```
%timeit res=gg.get_group(1)
2.76 ms ± 8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

timing is much longer and is just slightly faster than

```
%timeit res=df[df[1]==1]
6.87 ms ± 16.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

On the other hand, if we extract groups at first

```
%timeit gdict=df.groupby(1).groups
15.7 ms ± 35.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

then get group takes no time

```
%timeit gdict[1]
29.8 ns ± 0.0989 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

So my question is

1. why pandas designs `groupby` as lazy? In real application, I think I almost always  need to do many further operations on group object. If group object is lazy in splitting the dataframe at first, then a waste of time happens every time when done some operation like `get_group` etc.
2. I also don't understand " .groupby() does do some, but not all，of the splitting work by building a Grouping class instance for each key that you pass", what does it mean?
3. Is it possible to make groupby object not lazy?

Answer (score 1):

You need a bigger bechmark:

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,size=(100000000,4))) #3GB data
gg=df.groupby(1)
%time _ = gg.get_group(1) #first call slow
%time _ = gg.get_group(1) #fast
%time _ = gg.get_group(2) #other group lookup is also fast 
%timeit _ = gg.get_group(1) #gives wrong result
```

Groupby is lazy in that it doesn't calculate `groups` right away. It does so on the first request to them. Or when you use IPython and hit tab with `gg` under the cursor. It can be seen if you track memory consumption of the process. Or you can feel it in the IPython case.

It is difficult to guess what goes on under the hood but `get_group` seem to have its own cache, while `groups` and methods like `sum` or `min` have shared one. Probably attempts to minimize memory usage for distinct use cases. Anyway, **after the first usage the laziness is gone.**

The final test is wrong. `gg.groups` contains indexex, not groups themselves:

```
%timeit df.loc[gdict[1]]  #It is actually the slowest
1.23 s ± 26.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit df[df[1]==1]
928 ms ± 23.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit gg.get_group(1)
510 ms ± 30.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Retrieving items from the dictionary is indeed thousands times faster, however you would be trading space for speed.

If you're absolutely sure you need to run functions on the same group more than once, you can try sorting the dataframe on the column and saving the group slices.

```
%time df = df.sort_values(1,ignore_index=True)
#Wall time: 10.3 s
%time ids = df[1].diff().to_numpy().nonzero()[0]
#Wall time: 1.88 s
%time gl = {df[1][v] : slice(v,ids[i+1] if (i+1)<len(ids) else None) for i,v in enumerate(ids)}
#Wall time: 112 µs
%timeit df[gl[1]]
#12.1 µs ± 208 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Sorted data may be fastest for some use cases.

```
%timeit {k:df[v].sum() for k,v in gl.items()}
1.16 s ± 42.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit gg.sum()
2.73 s ± 29.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit {x: gg.get_group(x).sum() for x in range(1,10)}
4.23 s ± 61.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```